# TYPO3 (10.4) Felogin: Can´t change Template

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

i can´t change the Login.html template from the EXT:Felogin (10.4.4) in my TYPO3 (10.4.4 latest). 
I tried everything.

I changed the path with typoscript in:

1. Backend (constants and setup)
2. In my sitepackage (constants and setup)
3. I even changed the path in the original extension in typo3/sysext/felogin

and nothing worked for me.

Did anybody managed it to changed the template?

Comment: Please post the TypoScript you used.

Comment: Hi,
i tried this:

styles.content.loginform.templateFile = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Extensions/Login/Login.html
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.templateFile = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Extensions/Login/Login.html

Comment: Try to add the FILE behind the EXT. --> FILE:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Extensions/Login/Login.html

Comment: Nothing changed.
I tried this:
styles.content.loginform.templateFile = FILE:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Extensions/Login/Login.html
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.templateFile = FILE:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Extensions/Login/Login.html

Comment: Did you placed the TS as a constant definition? It worked for me when I placed it as a constant.

Comment: @Paul, yes i tested it everywhere, as setup as constant, like i wrote in my description. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 7):

In my case in Typo 10.4.6 (own Sitepackage = ***) this Setup works:

SETUP:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login {
  view {
    templateRootPaths.10 = EXT:***/Resources_felogin/Private/Templates/
    partialRootPaths.10 = EXT:***/Resources_felogin/Private/Partials/
  }
}
```

Now i can edit Login.html

Answer (score 5):

First it has to be verified which kind of template is used, as since TYPO3 version 10.2 there exist two different plugins and templates:

- The old-style template which is using markers in the form `###MARKER###`.
  This template relies on the old plugin which is still based on `piBase`
- The new `fluid`-based template is served by the new plugin which is based on `extbase`.

The switch between these two options is quite uncommon in the feature-settings resided, which can be found here:

[image: button in TYPO3 to open feature-toggles]

The fe_login-setting I found in the very bottom of the modal-window which is opening after having clicked on the button "Feature Toggle":

[image: Modal window for Feature Toggles]

If the button is activated and therefore shown green fluid-templates are used, else the old marker-template.

It still keeps to mention that the new plugin with fluid-templates inside the extension fe_login is not mentioned in the current official documentation but only in this [CHANGELOG](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.2/Feature-88102-FrontendLoginViaFluidAndExtbase.html)

Below I will show the solutions for fluid-templates.

---

**Settings for Fluid-Templates**

1. Enable fluid-templates like explained above if not done yet.
2. Add the TypoScript shown after the following image if it's missing (you can control it in the `Template-Tools` for TypoScript:

   [image: Template-Tools for TypoScript]

   Take care that you have to switch there between `constants` and `setup` to find the correct values if existing.

**TypoScript Constants:**

```
plugin {
  tx_felogin_login {
    view {
      # cat=Frontend Login/02_Template/102; type=string; label= Path to template root (FE)
      templateRootPath = EXT:felogin/Resources/Private/Templates/
      # cat=Frontend Login/02_Template/103; type=string; label= Path to template partials (FE)
      partialRootPath = EXT:felogin/Resources/Private/Partials/
      # cat=Frontend Login/02_Template/104; type=string; label= Path to template layouts (FE)
      layoutRootPath = EXT:felogin/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
  }
}
```

**TypoScript Setup:**

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login {
  view {
    templateRootPaths {
      0 = EXT:felogin/Resources/Private/Templates/
      10 = {$plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.templateRootPath}
    }

    partialRootPaths {
      0 = EXT:felogin/Resources/Private/Partials/
      10 = {$plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.partialRootPath}
    }

    layoutRootPaths {
      0 = EXT:felogin/Resources/Private/Layouts/
      10 = {$plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
  }
}
tt_content.login < tt_content.felogin_login
```

3. Save the record or the files, depending where you added the TypoScript and afterwards in the Template-Tools you can open the constant-editor to add your own values there.

[image]

Check the paths and adjust them to your needs. A copy of the fluid-files has naturally to exist in the paths that are entered in the form. They can be adjusted later, but it's advisable to add a headline or some other text for testing if the templates are taken from the right directory.

4. After clearing the cache the website can be reloaded for controlling if the steps succeeded. If the original templates are shown check all paths and if the templates reside without changes perhaps already in the right directories, just in original form. If nothing or only the headline is shown check if you added a plugin of type login-form and add it on the right page and in the right col if missing.

---

It has to be expected that in TYPO3 version 10.4.5 or later everything is much easier and some steps here are just not required, like adding the TypoScript-Snippets - they will probably soon reside in the original setup for the extension.

Comment: Sorry, but this solutions don´t works for me. I tried all steps three times and nothing changes.

Comment: If you still have other configuration that is not default: disable or delete it. Default configuration has to be loaded first and then this one - but if the noted configuration is missing anyway, then the loading order is unimportant as nothing is overwritten. Control that the new configuration can be seen in the constant editor and that all paths are correct, including upper/lower case.

Comment: Most important: check if the extension `fe_login` is enabled in the extension-manager and on the page where you want to display it it's added as Plugin with the correct settings. Also at least one user in the referenced sys-folder must exist.

Comment: furthermore you can check per phpmyadmin the `CType` of your login-plugin(s). it should be `login` but could be `felogin_login` too.

Answer (score 2):

It works here in a 10.4.3 installation:

TS (Setup):

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.10 = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/FeLogin/Templates
        partialRootPaths.10 = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/FeLogin/Partials
    }
}
```

And place your file in

```
sitepackage/Resources/Private/FeLogin/Templates/Login/Login.html
```

Comment: Thank your, for your response. 
I tried your solution but it doesn´t work.
I also fixed the typo in the Login.html path, from "Login" to "FeLogin", but no change.

Answer (score 0):

**The following answer is not correct but includes some links that might be of interest. For a step-by-step-description look for my second answer on this page.**

---

That seems being broken for me in the moment, I tried it out like you without success.
If an individual file-path is entered, the original template is not loaded anymore but the configured file neither.

I found two issues in the bugtracker that seem somewhow related:

- [Bug #90953: Add missing view path definition for felogin](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90953)
- [Task #90566: Provide examples of how to customize / extend the extbase plugin](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90566)

Its possible that there are still other issues reported related to it, but I never found any on a quick search. First step would be to search here:

- [Forge issues, category fe_login](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&set_filter=1&f%5B%5D=status_id&op%5Bstatus_id%5D=o&f%5B%5D=category_id&op%5Bcategory_id%5D=%3D&v%5Bcategory_id%5D%5B%5D=1002&f%5B%5D=&c%5B%5D=tracker&c%5B%5D=status&c%5B%5D=priority&c%5B%5D=subject&c%5B%5D=assigned_to&c%5B%5D=category&c%5B%5D=fixed_version&c%5B%5D=cf_7&group_by=&t%5B%5D=)

second step would be to rermove or change the search filter.

Finally you still can file a new issue, even without searching too much, it doesn't matter much if an issue is reported twice.

Comment: Thank you for your response and your testing i will look further in the typo3-forge.

Comment: I just found an open patch which adds some missing TypoScript https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/64080 - @dkoehl could you please try to set just this line in TypoScript setup? `plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.templateRootPaths.10=EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Extensions/Login/` - in there you would have a folder `Login/` and in there a file `Login.html` - here are the originals: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/tree/master/typo3/sysext/felogin/Resources/Private/Templates/Login

Comment: Nope, nothing changed.
The needed part of TypoScript in the EXT: Felogin is missing, like in the open patch, is fixed.

Comment: I tried the TypoScript-snippets of the fix already without success. You're sure you get the desired result in the frontend?

Comment: No, I didn't check yet. It requires the feature switch to use Fluid templates instead of marker templates.

Comment: Ok, see my 2nd answer in this page, it's a bit for dummies as I had to search everything too because I never knew about all the details ;-) I tried it and I got it working like described in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look here. https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/64080

Add this to your constants and setup override for felogin.
Works totally fine for me in TYPO3 10.4.9

#### Constants

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login {
  view {
    # cat=Frontend Login/02_Template/102; type=string; label= Path to template root (FE)
    templateRootPath = EXT:providerExt/Resources/Private/Templates/FeLogin/
    # cat=Frontend Login/02_Template/103; type=string; label= Path to template partials (FE)
    partialRootPath = EXT:providerExt/Resources/Private/Partials/FeLogin/
    # cat=Frontend Login/02_Template/104; type=string; label= Path to template layouts (FE)
    layoutRootPath = EXT:providerExt/Resources/Private/Layouts/FeLogin/
  }
}
```

#### Setup

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login {
  view {
    templateRootPaths.10 = {$plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.templateRootPath}
    partialRootPaths.10 = {$plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.partialRootPath}
    layoutRootPaths.10 = {$plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.layoutRootPath}
  }
}
```

Path to Login.html Override in Template Folder
`providerExt/Resources/Private/Templates/FeLogin/Login/Login.html`